# SwiftUI: replacing custom map button with a MapPin as a button?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I was using a custom button on a map but I realized now I want to use a normal pin, such as `MapPin`.  How can I change my code to adjust for the use of `MapPin` so that when I click on it, the same actions take place .

```
   Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: getAnnotated()) { item in
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: item.coordinate) {
                Button(action: {
                    selected.item = item  // <--- here
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }){
                    Image("icon")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(9.0)
                }
                .background(Circle())
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
            }
        }
```

I tried swapping out `Image()` for `MapPin()` as a last ditch effort but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: getAnnotated()) { item in
    MapAnnotation(coordinate: item.coordinate) {
        Button(action: {
            selected.item = item
            showSheet.toggle()
        }){
            Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")  // <---
                .scaleEffect(2.0)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .padding()
        }
        .background(Circle())
        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)  // <---
    }
}
```

or "mappin.circle", "mappin"

and adjust the colors as you see fit.

Comment: this works great.  Thanks for all your help again :)